# How to check if the mail client is installed in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, email

I have WPF desktop application, witch contains mail link. If you click on the link, the default mail client opens. But if the machine does not have a configured e-mail client, the program crashes with a critical exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: The object reference does not point to an instance of the object.
at Nvx.ReDoc.DesktopUi.View.Tray.Sections.About.AboutWindow.OnRequestNavigate(Object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e) 



  <Other:ReDocHyperlinkLite NavigateUri="mailto:mail@mail.com?subject=sampleText" RequestNavigate="OnRequestNavigate">
<Run Text="mail@mail.com"/></Other:ReDocHyperlinkLite>
```

OnRequestNavigate implementation is

```
private void OnRequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

How to check if there is an installed mail client on the computer, and catch an exception?

Comment: Hi, please post the exception as [edit] of your post.

Comment: What's the value of `EmailNavigateUri` and what's the implementation of `OnRequestNavigate`? I think you shouldn't get an error but a prompt should be displayed to choose a mail client

Comment: Catch the exception and display a MessageBox or similar that explains that there was no default mail app found?

Comment: mm8 yes, exactly

Comment: So your question is answered? Or don't you know how to catch an exception?

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether an application is registered to handle the `mailto` URI scheme (and additionally check if the given application really exists):

```
private bool IsSchemeRegistered(string scheme)
{
    using (var schemeKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(scheme))
    {
        if (schemeKey == null)
            return false;

        if (schemeKey.GetValue("") == null || !schemeKey.GetValue("").ToString().StartsWith("URL:"))
            return false;

        using (var shellKey = schemeKey.OpenSubKey("shell"))
        {
            if (shellKey == null)
                return false;

            using (var openKey = shellKey.OpenSubKey("open"))
            {
                if (openKey == null)
                    return false;

                using (var commandKey = openKey.OpenSubKey("command"))
                {
                    if (commandKey == null)
                        return false;

                    var command = commandKey.GetValue("") as string;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(command) || !File.Exists(command.Split(new[] { '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First()))
                        return false;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This method be called like this:

```
if ( !IsSchemeRegistered("mailto") )
{  
     MessageBox.Show("No mail client installed/configured");
}
else
{
    //...
}
```